# Access denied for user 'user'@'%' to database 'db'

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

What is this error ?
mysql user, password, and Db its seem completely correct,
Am using freehosting.com what should i do right now ?? :(

```
error_reporting(0);
session_start();
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "user", "password", "db");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

/* return name of current default database */
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT DATABASE()")) {
    $row = $result->fetch_row();
    printf("Default database is %s.\n", $row[0]);
    $result->close();
}

/* change db to world db */
$mysqli->select_db("world");

/* return name of current default database */
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT DATABASE()")) {
    $row = $result->fetch_row();
    printf("Default database is %s.\n", $row[0]);
    $result->close();
}

$mysqli->close();
```

> Access denied for user 'user'@'%' to database 'db'

Comment: have space before and after ? `" password " `

Comment: @Mohsen Shakibafa, :( no sir, just edited, it's not having space

Comment: can you check privilege for user `user`?

Comment: so you have user with username `user` and password with value `password`? and your database is named `db`?

Comment: @Mohsen Shakibafa: there're not button privilege in Phpmyadmin

Comment: @ mitkosoft, no sir, it just example text of user and db in here :(

Comment: @AhSear , go to your phpmyadmin , then select your database , then in top menu you must have `privilege` menu , click on it , then you can see users and Privileges

Comment: see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-connecting.html

Comment: @Mohsen Shakibafa: as i told you dear, there're no this button appear , i don't know why

Comment: modifie $mysqli = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "user", "password", "db"); par $mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "db");

Comment: @ bhrached: already done this method, but still appear this connection error,

Comment: is what you tried to log on the command line

Comment: Check the user has the correct **privileges** - it seems the connection was never refused, when you try to do your queries: it seems your user doesn't have permissions to insert or edit to that Table.

Comment: Thank you everyone who try to solve my problem, i solved this problem by changing hosting site to other one but now i get stack one more problem, my domain was on goddady.com, and now i changed hosting nameserver in godaddy.com from freehosting.com  to 000webhost.com, when i go to my website www.elitelagaysl.com sometime its redirect me to 404 page and sometimes its appear my website ?? anyone understand why ?